# How to change fuerte's gazebo view way back to electric version?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I like the electric way of mouse to view gazebo more better than fuerte way.

How to change back?

Is there any options?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41043/how-to-change-fuerte%27s-gazebo-view-way-back-to-electric-version?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the GUI menu-bar, select "View-->FPS View Control".

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1